# Reflection of light from function graph

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

Let a positive convex decreasing differentiable function $f(x)$ be defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$. Let the point light source be placed at $P(x_0,y_0)$ with $y_0>0,\,y_0 <f(x_0)$. Light is assumed to be reflected from the plot $y=f(x)$ and the $x$-axis. Does there exist a number $R$ s. t. the part of the graph $y=f(x)$ for $x>R$ is not lightened?

A model example $f(x):=e^{-x},\,P(0,0.5)$ suggests the answer is yes.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198207/reflection-of-light-from-function-graph

Comment: @user64494 You probably should have linked the cross-posting in the post. And it is preferred not to post the same thing on two site almost simultaneously. See [this post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088). (Maybe other posts tagged [meta-tag:cross-posting] or [meta-tag:migration] might be of interest for you, too.)

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak : Having obtained no feedback to my question during about 20 hours, I decided to repost that in MO: a normal reaction of a normal person.